# Dialog framework doesn't work

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

i am trying to apply the basic sample for rendering a page inside a dialog as in the showcase
http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/dialogFrameworkBasic.jsf

- my web pages are under **webapp/pages/general**
- i am running **PrimeFaces-4.0-SNAPSHOT** on **Mojarra-2.1.20**
- i have two pages: 
      1- home.xhtml
      2- viewreport.xhtml

**1- home.xhtml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ice="http://www.icesoft.com/icefaces/component"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:pretty="http://ocpsoft.com/prettyfaces"
    xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">
<h:head>


    <title>Welcome</title>
    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="style.css" />
</h:head>

<h:body dir="rtl">

    <h:form>
        <p:commandButton value="View" icon="ui-icon-extlink"
            action="dialog:viewreport" />
    </h:form>

</h:body>

</html>
```

**2- viewreport.xhtml:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head>

</h:head>

<h:body>
    <h:panelGroup id="report_details_new" layout="block" style="width:500px;height:500px;">

      HELLO WORLD


    </h:panelGroup>
   </h:body>

   </html>
```

when clicking on the button, nothing happens, i don't get any errors in eclipse console or in browser console.

please advise why the dialog framework is not working.

Comment: You need some configuration like dialogviewhandler, dialogactionlistener and so on, these are undocumented since feature is alpha right now. See faces-config of showcase for the config.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Solved by adding the following configuration to the **faces-config.xml**:

```
    <action-listener>org.primefaces.application.DialogActionListener</action-listener>
    <navigation-handler>org.primefaces.application.DialogNavigationHandler</navigation-handler>
    <view-handler>org.primefaces.application.DialogViewHandler</view-handler>
```

tested on IE9,Chrome,Firefox for **primefaces 4.0-SNAPSHOT**

Comment: This also needs to go within:
        <application>
            
        </application>